# Trimming a string from the end in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, trim

In Javascript, how can I trim a string by a number of characters from the end, append another string, and re-append the initially cut-off string again?

In particular, I have `filename.png` and want to turn it into `filename-thumbnail.png`.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
var sImage = "filename.png";
var sAppend = "-thumbnail";
var sThumbnail = magicHere(sImage, sAppend);
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward string manipulation. Quirksmode has a good introduction. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice, that should be useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.slice`, which accepts negative indexes:

```
function insert(str, sub, pos) {
    return str.slice(0, pos) + sub          + str.slice(pos);
    //     "filename"        + "-thumbnail" + ".png"
}
```

Usage:

```
insert("filename.png", "-thumbnail", -4); // insert at 4th from end
```

Comment: This is a very handy function that could work well in multiple instances. The only potential issue I see is that the file extension may not always be 4 chars (including the `.`).

Comment: @Colin O'Dell: Yes, that's correct. I did not use something like regexps because the OP only stated "a number of characters from the end".

Answer (score 3):

Try using a regular expression (Good documentation can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

I haven't tested but try something like:

```
var re = /(.*)\.png$/;  
var str = "filename.png";  
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1-thumbnail.png");  
console.log(newstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to find the various parts of the filename and then rearrange and add strings as needed from there.

Something like this:

```
var file='filename.png';

var re1='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))';
var re2='.*?';
var re3='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))';

var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3,["i"]);
var m = p.exec(file);
if (m != null) {
    var fileName=m[1];
    var fileExtension=m[2]; 
}
```

That would give you your file's name in fileName and file's extension in fileExtension. From there you could append or prepend anything you want.

```
var newFile = fileName + '-thumbnail' + '.' + fileExtension;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simpler than regular expressions, you could use lastindexof (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) to find the file extension (look for the period - this allows for longer file extensions like .html), then use slice as suggested by pimvdb.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and do something like this:

```
var sImage = "filename.png";
var sAppend = "-thumbnail$1";
var rExtension = /(\.[\w\d]+)$/;

var sThumbnail = sImage.replace(rExtension, sAppend);
```

`rExtension` is a regular expression which looks for the extension, capturing it into `$1`.  You'll see that `$1` appears inside of `sAppend`, which means "put the extension here".

**EDIT:** This solution will work with any file extension of any length.  See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4Qsv/